# Local Variable might ne referenced before assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have two dictionaries 1.Primary, 2. Secondary

Need to check first field of both dictionary

If field is same compare the title with primary and secondary

*If field and title is same then From Primary dictionary add count to secondary dictionary

Primary dictionary

```
primary = {"Latest":[
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Developer",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
}
]}
secondary = [
  {
    "name": "Employee",
    "field": "employee",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "A",
        "paragraph": "Test",
        "count": "null"
      },
      {
        "title": "B",
        "paragraph": "B",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Project",
    "field": "project",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "NEW_York",
        "paragraph": "test",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "field": "designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "title": "Developer",
        "paragraph": "null",
        "count": "null"
      }
    ]
}
]
```

Code is below

```
def test(second,primary):
    for secondary_value in second:
        for value in primary:
            if secondary_value['title'] ==  value['title']:
                secondary_value['count'] = value['count']
     return secondary_value

for primary in primary['Latest']:
    for secondary_elem in secondary:
        if secondary_elem['field'] == primary['field']:
            test(secondary_elem['values'],primary['values'])
secondary
```

Above code is working fine, but it showing logical error in ide. Local Variable  might ne referenced before assignment  How to fix this

Comment: Your IDE shouldn't give you this warning with this code. Which IDE do you use?

Comment: pycharm is the ide

Comment: I copied your code to PyCharm 2020.2.3 and got no such message. (I even modified the code with an extra variable to see if this message isn't suppressed in my configuration and it was working fine)

Comment: return second fixed my issue

Comment: Why does ``test`` return anything at all? It is customary for functions/methods that modify their arguments/owner to return nothing/``None`` (e.g. ``list.sort``) or non-argument/owner values (e.g. ``dict.pop``).

Comment: I agree with @MisterMiyagi. And you edited your post and changed the indentation of the `return` statement. Now, with this changed indentation, it's clear where the warning comes from. If `second` is empty in the function then `secondary_value` is never set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test(second,primary):
    for secondary_value in second:
        for value in primary:
            if secondary_value['title'] ==  value['title']:
                secondary_value['count'] = value['count']
     return second

for primary in primary['Latest']:
    for secondary_elem in secondary:
        if secondary_elem['field'] == primary['field']:
            test(secondary_elem['values'],primary['values'])
secondary
```

Comment: The warning in your original code was being generated as, if if `second` was empty, then `secondary_value` would be an undefined name as no loop would execute.